# Group list of dictionaries based on key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-manipulation

I have a array that looks like this

```
comp_data = [
  {
    "product_id": 432263,
    "price_zone_id": 1,
    "oreilly_price": 0,
    "amazon_price": 0,
    "az_price": 0,
    "rockauto_price": 0,
    "napa_price": 0,
    "oreilly_index": 0,
    "amazon_index": 0,
    "az_index": 0,
    "rockauto_index": 0,
    "napa_index": 0,
    "weighted_comp_price": 0,
    "weighted_comp_index": 0,
    "week": None
  }
]
```

Skipping the fields product_id and price_zone_id, I want to create a list of dictionaries by mapping the names of each key. For Example

You can see amazon_price, amazon_index, ultimately I want a list that looks like this

```
[
    {
        'amazon_price': 0,
        'amazon_index': 0,
        'name': 'Amazon' --> This would be simply adding .title() to the name. 
    },
    {
        'az_price': 0,
        'az_index': 0,
        'name': 'Az' --> This would be simply adding .title() to the name. 
    },
    {
        'orielly_price': 0,
        'orielly_index': 0,
        'name': 'ORielly' --> This would be simply adding .title() to the name. 
    }
]
```

My current code looks like this and is generating wrong output

```
stores_data = {}
for data in comp_data:
    dict_keys = data.keys()
    for keys in dict_keys:
        if keys != 'product_id' and keys != 'price_zone_id':
            store_name = keys.split('_')[0]
            value_type = keys.split('_')[-1]
            stores[store_name][value_type] =  {}
```

Stores are eassentially the string infront of _index or _price. ex amazon_index, store would be amazon

For this key  `"weighted_comp_price"`, the store would be Weighted Comp

Comment: Like foe each pair if keys `_price` and `_index` ? Is there only on element in the first array ? If not, do the same for each dict ?

Comment: Yes, basically construct a dictionary if you found amazon_price, then create a dictionary with amazon_price and amazon_index

Comment: What is "stores"?

Comment: You can choose either _price or _index to grab the name, then add those values within the dictionary.

Comment: @BuddyBobIII Added answer to your question in the main thread. Stores are essentially ex amazon_price and amazon_index, the store would be 'Amazon', we do .split('_') on the key then do .title() on it to create the store name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `dict`

1. Find the `_price` keys
2. Verify you have the corresponding `_index` key
3. Save it

```
stores_data = []
for data in comp_data:
    for price_key in (k for k in data if k.endswith("_price")):
        name = price_key.rsplit("_", maxsplit=1)[0]
        index_key = f'{name}_index'
        if index_key in data:
            stores_data.append({price_key: data[price_key], index_key: data[index_key], 'name': name.title()})
```

Giving

```
[{'oreilly_price': 0, 'oreilly_index': 0, 'name': 'Oreilly'}, 
 {'az_price': 0, 'az_index': 0, 'name': 'Az'}, 
 {'napa_price': 0, 'napa_index': 0, 'name': 'Napa'}, 
 {'amazon_price': 0, 'amazon_index': 0, 'name': 'Amazon'}, 
 {'rockauto_price': 0, 'rockauto_index': 0, 'name': 'Rockauto'}, 
 {'weighted_comp_price': 0, 'weighted_comp_index': 0, 'name': 'Weighted_Comp'}]
```

Comment: I like the concept of looking for `endswith` instead of excluding specific names.  He missed `week` in his code.

Comment: This does not seem to handle weight_comp_price and weighted_comp_index

Comment: @newbieprogrammer095 yes, just fixed it :)

Comment: Thank you! A small request, you know how we are store oreilly_price, is it possible to just store it as 'price', since we already have name key field to identify which store it belongs to. Example {'price':0, 'index': 0, 'name': 'Oreilly'} instead of orielly_price, orielly_index

Comment: @newbieprogrammer095 you should be able to do it by yourself , change the key that it stored ;)

Comment: stores_data.append({'price': data[price_key], 'index': data[index_key], 'name': name.title()} , looks right? (: Thank you again! PS. Marked this answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating "price" and "index" instead of the whole name.  Which did you want?

```
comp_data = [
  {
    "product_id": 432263,
    "price_zone_id": 1,
    "oreilly_price": 0,
    "amazon_price": 0,
    "az_price": 0,
    "rockauto_price": 0,
    "napa_price": 0,
    "oreilly_index": 0,
    "amazon_index": 0,
    "az_index": 0,
    "rockauto_index": 0,
    "napa_index": 0,
    "weighted_comp_price": 0,
    "weighted_comp_index": 0,
    "week": None
  }
]

stores = {}
for data in comp_data:
    for key,value in data.items():
        if key not in ('product_id','price_zone_id','week'):
            words = key.split('_')
            store_name ='_'.join(words[:-1])
            value_type = words[-1]
            if store_name not in stores:
                stores[store_name] = {'name': store_name.title()}
            stores[store_name][key] = value

from pprint import pprint
pprint(stores)
```

Output:

```
{'amazon': {'amazon_index': 0, 'amazon_price': 0, 'name': 'Amazon'},
 'az': {'az_index': 0, 'az_price': 0, 'name': 'Az'},
 'napa': {'name': 'Napa', 'napa_index': 0, 'napa_price': 0},
 'oreilly': {'name': 'Oreilly', 'oreilly_index': 0, 'oreilly_price': 0},
 'rockauto': {'name': 'Rockauto', 'rockauto_index': 0, 'rockauto_price': 0},
 'weighted_comp': {'name': 'Weighted_Comp',
                   'weighted_comp_index': 0,
                   'weighted_comp_price': 0}}
```